# Content change within div Parallax Website

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

Is it possible to change content in parallax website with in div, like slide don't change and only particular div is change with its content?

Image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFMCq.jpg

Comment: can you please describe a little bit more?

Comment: In parallax design I'm trying on scrolling on second slide, slide will not change only content and graph will change on same slide (slide 2).